# How to loop through one table and update a field based on data in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. table_1 and table_2. table_1 contains a few columns but the two i need are table_1.id and table_1.contact_id. table_2 contains a blank column table_2.related_contact and a column filled in table_2.cid. table_2.cid and table_1.id are the same.

I want to loop through table_2 based on table_2.cid and where table_2.cid = table_1.id UPDATE table_2.related_contact with the value from table_1.contact_id for that same row.

My SQL knowledge is okay, but this is beyond me. I have looked at other answers but cannot find one fitting of this example.

Example Before Loop:

Table 1

```
id: 3745        contact_id: ae456-78ef
Id: 3746        contact_id: oi958=34hb
```

Table 2

```
cid:3745         related_contact: NULL
cid:3746         related_contact: NULL
```

After Loop:

Table 2

```
cid: 3745         related_contact: ae456-78ef
cid: 3746         related_contact: oi958=34hb
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQL UPDATE syntax (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) putting special focus in `table_references`  as described in Section 13.2.10, “SELECT Syntax” (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

```
UPDATE table_2 t2 
INNER JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.id=t2.cid 
SET 
t2.related_contact=t1.contact_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  a loop  you could use a update based on a join

```
update table2 
inner join table1 on table1.id = table2.id 
set table2.related_contact = table1.contact_id
```